# How to remove the reputation using json arrays in php I want to make them as a unique as given in the circle

Tags: php, json, api, codeigniter

I want to make these arrays as a unique as it is marked in encircled. It should not be repeated the same.

```
$session_activity_category = array();

array_walk($search_venue, function($venue_b) use (&$session_activity_category) {
    $categories = $this->users_model->search_categories_by_session($venue_b->activity_venue_id);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $session_activity_category[] = $category;
    }
});


 return $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_status_header(200)
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('activity_category'=>$session_activity_category,'activity'=>$session_activity,'activity_session'=>$search_session,'activity_venue'=>$search_venue),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)  
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Is result good for you if you apply `array_unique($session_activity_category)`?

Comment: Please don't add JSON (or code) as images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

î think the best would be, to give a unique key to your array

Something like the following should work

```
$session_activity_category = array();

array_walk($search_venue, function($venue_b) use (&$session_activity_category) {
    $categories = $this->users_model->search_categories_by_session($venue_b->activity_venue_id);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $session_activity_category[$category->venue_id.$category->activity_cat_id] = $category;
    }
});

return $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_status_header(200)
    ->set_output(
        json_encode(
            array(
                'activity_category' => array_values($session_activity_category),
                'activity' => $session_activity,
                'activity_session' => $search_session,
                'activity_venue' => $search_venue
            ),
        JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)  
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!